black insert stuck in tube light fixture
I removed a dead tube light by rotation from the fixture and when I went to put in a new tube light, I noticed it wouldn’t even insert into the fixture. Closer examination shows that the inner black ring has been rotated that it now blocks the entry for the tube light prong insertion. Is it possible to rotate the inner black ring?

use nose pliers and rotate...you will be killed if the power is on

Yes, you need a special key to rotate that thing.  The key has two pins about 1/4" long, and spaced about 1/2" apart from each other.  The pins would be on the end of a stick, and importantly, insulated.
In my mind's eye I imagine the "stick" part being made of hollow glass and either white colored or dark purple.  Not sure where to acquire one!  /wink
Seriously. though... use a fluorescent tube as the tool.

Yes, you should be able to rotate that black ring 90 degrees to allow a bulb to slide in, then rotate into contact position.  Just make sure power is off to the fixture before trying to get close with fingers or other tool to prevent electrical shock.
